# Why it does not create the table and add data?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

DatabaseHelper.java:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "daysDATABASE.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "daysDATABASE";
    private static final String COL1 = "datez";
    private static final String COL2 = "json";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, datez TEXT, json TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String date, String json) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("datez", date);
        contentValues.put("json", json);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper mydb;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diary);

        mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mydb.addData("02164987", "adsdsadsadsadsadsadsa");
    }
```

If I open the database, there is no table in it, nor data ofc.. since the table is not created.

..........................................................................................................................................................

I would tell more informations but I do not think you need more than this 2 java class. I copy pasted and changed some stuff from tutorialspoint tutorial but seems like it does not work for some reason.

Comment: The application throws some exception?

Comment: Do not think any of these related to this problem: https://www.pastiebin.com/5bd85bbcbf43a

Answer (score 3):

Even if your table was created, you could not add data in it with the `addData()` method because you don't supply a value for the `id` column.  
The `CREATE` statement creates the column `id` as `PRIMARY KEY` but not `AUTOINCREMENT` so you must supply its value. But I don't think that this is what you want.  
So change the `CREATE` statement to this:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, datez TEXT, json TEXT)");
```

then uninstall the app from the emulator/device so the db is deleted and run again.  
This way the `onCreate()` method will be executed and the table will be created.  
**Edit1**: remember to close the database object after you're done with it:

```
mydb.close()
```

**Edit2**: the `insert()` method, if successful, returns the id of the new added row or -1 if there was a problem, so I suggest you make this change in `addData()` method:

```
int id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues); 
return (id >= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to forpas answer which solves the root cause of the problem, i will suggest you use

`db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);`

instead of `db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);` so you can get a clue of what the problem might be.